# Mic is not working on the zoom call only

Tags: sound, microphone

I have installed Zoom in two ways:

- by terminal and
- by the available app in the store

Both have the same issue. The microphone is working on my laptop, but it is not working in the Zoom setting, even though it shows the mic name. In the Zoom setting, the mic is not muted, but still, the issue is coming.

[image]

How to get the microphone to work in the Zoom call?

Comment: You say that the microphone works on your laptop. Which program do you take to test this?

Comment: Can you select the specific mic in the Zoom settings instead of choosing "same as system"

Comment: @questionto42
on zoom the mic is not working. i tested it with installing zoom on my mobile then i did call the voice is going but the issue is that the mic icon in zoom screen did not go green up and down

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i tried both the mic saystem and external both has same issuue. i dont know why it is happening

Comment: How did you install Zoom? Is it a snap app? In that case, switching to the APT app should fix the issue. Please tell us the exact command with which you installed zoom, and we can provide a potential solution

Comment: Has it ever worked on your laptop? Now you say you tested it on your mobile. That does not count. How do you know that your laptop mic works so that only Zoom is the problem?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi
Sudo dpkg -i (the file name)

Comment: @questionto42
this icon did not go up https://imgur.com/TlN47HY

Comment: I am new to ubuntu. Thank you both of you for helping me. 
I relly appreciate both of you for helping me

Comment: I ask again: do you have any proof that your mic is working on your laptop at all? Which app is working with it? Did you check it in the sound settings? Your picture shows again just the Zoom app.